# Help identifying a kanji character

Tags: kanji

[image: unknown kanji]

I usually don't have trouble identifying kanji what with all the helpful dictionary apps available. But this one really has me scratching my head.

I tried to find this character by building it up with radicals, unfortunately the closest I came to is 鎚 which of course has a different radical on the left ('gold' whereas the one in my image has the 'thread radical') Initially I thought maybe  鎚 is an alternative way to write this mystery Kanji, but I looked it up in a reliable dictionary and it doesn't list any alternatives. So can anyone help identify this kanji? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your dictionary has sound-basis lookup, すがる will lead you to '縋 '

Answer (score 5):

Both Jisho and [漢字辞典オンライン](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjij/4794.html) have it under 糸.

> - [[縋]{すが｝りつく](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%B8%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F)
>
>   1. to cling to; to depend on; to embrace; to hug
> - [縋](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%B8%8B%20%23kanji)
>     cling, hang on, depend
>     Kun: すが.る
>     On: ツイ

(Jisho)